# Updating api gateway to vpc link through cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-vpc

I have a api gateway set up as follows:

[image]

Now I need to update the above set up to to vpc link and the same url so at the end I want to convert it to:

[image]

As you see I can do it through console.Can I do the above through cli as well?

I found the following I cannot get a working example.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-method.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-rest-api.html

Can anyone help? is it supported at all?

Answer (score 1):

Its is supported. You are looking for update-integration command 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-integration.html

with connectionType is VPC_LINK

Comment: thanks here is my command : aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id 68ez95xgb1 --resource-id u72twj --uri 'awseb-AWSEB-EUBD7GNSIWZS-07xxxx' --http-method GET --type HTTP_PROXY --integration-http-method GET --connection-type VPC_LINK --connection-id xxxx

Comment: when I run it I get Unknown options: --connection-type, --connection-id, gq0oak, VPC_LINK

Comment: can you give an example please? what patch operation should I use?

Comment: put-integration should also work. are you using latest version aws cli ?

Comment: Yeah I do. I just tried the update you provided but still the same issue

Comment: Here is my update command: aws apigateway update-integration --rest-api-id 68ez95xgb1 --resource-id u72twj --http-method GET [{"op": "replace","path": "/connectionType","value": "VPC_LINK"}]

Comment: and here is what I got: Unknown options: replace,path:, /connectionType,value:, VPC_LINK}], [{op:

Comment: Still think you are using wrong version of aws cli. You can check it here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I managed to solve it by upgrading to the latest aws cli:

```
pip install awscli --upgrade --user
```

Afterwards, restart your terminal to make sure you load your latest cli